# Can't get "Registration Confirmation" works in FOSUserBundle in my own function

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

I'm trying to get "Registration Confirmation" working on my application but can't. Since I need to set some fields on profiles and so on this is how my method `save` for users is:

public function saveAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

```
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $entityProfile = new SysPerfil();
    $formProfile = $this->createForm(new PerfilType(), $entityProfile);
    $formProfile->handleRequest($request);

    $user_data = $request->get('user_profile');

    if ($formProfile->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($formProfile, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

        $role = $request->get('user_profile')['roleType'];

        $user->setUsername($user_data['rif']);
        $user->setEmail($user_data['user']['email']);
        $user->setPlainPassword($user_data['user']['password']);

        if ($role === "O") {
            $user->addRole("ROLE_OPERADOR");
        }
        elseif ($role === "CH") {
            $user->addRole("ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO");
        }

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $entityProfile->setUser($user);
        $em->persist($entityProfile);
        $em->flush();

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request));

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
    }
    else {
        $errors = $this->getFormErrors($formProfile);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array('status' => true, 'errors' => $errors));
}
```

And this is what I've configured at `config.yml` file:

```
# FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Sunahip\UserBundle\Entity\SysUsuario
    group:
        group_class: Sunahip\UserBundle\Entity\SysGrupos
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Attempted to call method "setEnabled" on class "UserBundle\Entity\SysPerfil" in /var/www
>   /html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/EventListener
>   /EmailConfirmationListener.php line 50.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was so never mind, my entities was bad configured and I was doing things bad, anyway thanks